# MySQL groupby time time difference

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have a data like this

```
id  timestamp       ticket_id
2   6/16/16 8:14    1466089815
10  6/27/16 7:15    1466089815
3   6/16/16 8:14    1466089816
11  6/27/16 7:15    1466089816
13  6/27/16 7:50    1466089816
```

I am trying to find the time taken by tiket_id. Is there a simple function which can be used to a groupby and take a time difference.

Here I am trying to find the time taken by the ticket_id. 
Eg:

```
ticket_id    time_taken
1466089816   10.93
```

Appreciate the support

Best
Jagan

Comment: Time difference between what? You've got one time listed per ID, meaning a total of two times for ticket 1466089815 and three for ticket 1466089816. Your expected results (and possibly the rationale for them) would be helpful.

Comment: @RDFozz Here is the result I am trying .Here I am trying to find the time taken by the ticket_id. 
Eg:

    ticket_id    time_taken
    1466089816   10.93   . I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the date/time difference between the first and the last timestamp of each ticket, there are several functions that can help you:

```
select 
    ticket_id,
    timediff(max(timestamp), min(timestamp))              as diff,
    timestampdiff(hour, min(timestamp), max(timestamp))   as diff_in_hours,
    timestampdiff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as diff_in_minutes,
    timestampdiff(second, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as diff_in_seconds
from tickets
group by ticket_id ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6e8eac85c8c96812e08c5a41401de375)**:

> ```
> select ticket_id,
>        timediff(max(timestamp), min(timestamp)) as diff,
>        timestampdiff(hour, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as diff_in_hours,
>        timestampdiff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as diff_in_minutes,
>        timestampdiff(second, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) as diff_in_seconds
> from tickets
> group by ticket_id ;
> ```
>
> ```
>  ticket_id | diff      | diff_in_hours | diff_in_minutes | diff_in_seconds
> ---------: | :-------- | ------------: | --------------: | --------------:
> 1466089815 | 263:01:00 |           263 |           15781 |          946860
> 1466089816 | 263:36:00 |           263 |           15816 |          948960
> ```

Comment: Thanks. That is a cool solution. I will expand this code to resolve my issue. Appreciate the wonderful support.